# pass List from Jquery to view

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I want to pass list from jquery ajax to the particular view. In a view user select the type. If they select first type, then it will load two lists and pass to the particular view data. How to do this in Ajax Jquery?

```
<%:Html.RadioButtonFor(model=> model.Type, 1)%>  Type 1
<%:Html.RadioButtonFor(model=> model.Type, 2)%>  Type 2

$("#Type").change(function () {
  var type = $("#Type");
  if (type == 1) {
    //*****The following things are added from controller. i want to pass the following lists from ajax*******/
    List<SelectListItem> type= new List<SelectListItem>();
    type.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "one", Value = "14" });
    type.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "two", Value = "12" });
  }
});
```

how to do this

Comment: First it needs to be `var type = $("#Type").val();` in order to return either `1` or `2`. What do you mean _i want to pass the following lists from ajax_? Do you want to pass the value `1` or `2` to a controller method and return some items to populate a `<select>`?

Answer (score 0):

I'm presuming that you want to submit the form to pass the value to the view?

If so, in the view with the form elements have the AJAX call:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#the-form-id").on("submit", function(e) {
       e.preventDefault();
       $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: "/your-controller-name/your-action-name,
          data: $("#the-form-id").serialize(),
          success: function(data) {
              //do something with the View that is returned...
          }
       });
    });
});
</script>
```

Then, you;'ll need an action in the controller the AJAX is calling that accepts the "data" being passed from the form. In ASP MVC, this will normally be a corresponding Model.

Said action will return a View set up however you want it to be. The original AJAX call will receive this so you can utilize it however you want to.

Hope that helps.